# Copy content of email body with particular subject into numbers app

Tags: automation, applescript, applescript-numbers

I am trying to get all emails from particular account (as I have four) with certain subject and then take content of those mails and write them into a numbers app with AppleScript.

Mail body contains personal info like email, date of birth, and so on which I am trying to organize into columns. 
Every new email goes into its own row.

If you know solution which includes Javascript or Automator I am open to it.

Here's what I have for now:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set LinkRemoval to make new document
    set theSheet to active sheet of LinkRemoval
    set value of cell "D1" of table 1 of theSheet to "E-mail"
    set value of cell "C1" of table 1 of theSheet to "Year Of Birth"
    set value of cell "B1" of table 1 of theSheet to "Name"
    set value of cell "A1" of table 1 of theSheet to "Phone Number"
end tell

tell application "Mail"
    set theRow to 2
    set theAccount to "MyAccount"
    get account theAccount
    set theMessages to {messages of inbox whose read status is false and subject contains "Application 2019"}
    set theContent to content of theMessages
end tell

on SetMessage(theMessage, theRow, theSheet)
    tell application "Numbers"
        set theRange to "D" & theRow
        set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theContent
    end tell
end SetMessage
```

Unfortunately, I get error:

*error "Can’t get content of {{message id 33410 of mailbox \"INBOX\" of account id \"22ED50FB-BF71-4D0A-A96B-9A78E4F57C8\" of application \"Mail\"*

Does anyone have a solution to this issue? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content accessing to this one liner:

```
set theContent to {the content of every message of inbox whose read status is false and subject contains "Application 2019"}
```

This should give you a list of the body of each message found.